# Can Spring EL (SpEL) be configured to accept null arguments in method calls?

Tags: spring, el, spring-el

I have the expression:

`obj1.doSomething(obj2, obj3)`

I want the method `obj1.doSomething` being called even when `obj2` or `obj3` are `null`.  The SPeL context is the one created by Spring MVC when a JSP page is rendered. If `obj2` (or `obj3`) is null I am getting a `SpelEvaluationException: Field or property ‘obj2’ cannot be found on null`

Note: I am using Jboss 5.1 and JSP EL 2.0. I know the EL expression `${obj1.doSomething(obj2, obj3)}` does what I want but only works on JSP EL 2.2.

Thanks!